# Clojure Koan Factorial Function Implementations

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm learning clojure and going through the [clojure-koan](http://clojurekoans.com/) exercises.  One of the exercises is about [implementing a factorial function](https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans/blob/master/src/koans/14_recursion.clj).  While I was playing around I noticed:

My recursive implementation seems to work for large numbers:

```
(defn factorial-1 [n]
   (loop [n n f 1]
      (if (= n 1)
          f
          (recur (dec n) (* f n)))))
```

Calling `(factorial-1 1000N)` in a REPL yields a number: `402387260077093773...`

However when I try the following lazy sequence approach:

```
(defn factorial-2 [n]
   (reduce * 1 (range 1 (inc n))))
```

Calling `(factorial-2 1000N)` in a REPL yields an error:

```
ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1388)
```

Why does the seemingly lazy sequence approach result in an integer overflow error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or you can simply use [`*'`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*') function.

```
(defn factorial-3 [n]
  (reduce *' (range 1 (inc n))))
```

`*'` function supports arbitrary precision. It will return `Long` if the number is in the range of `Long`. If the range exceeds the Long range, it will return `BigInt`.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know about the [*'](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*') function.  I assume by the presence of this function in the `clojure.core` namespace that this considered more idiomatic clojure.

Answer (score 8):

You never actually use any bigints in your multiplications, despite passing 1000N, because you only use that number to determine the *end* of your computation. You start multiplications at `1`, and multiply by `1`, then `2`, and so on. If you modify your definition of `factorial-2` to use a bigint, you get the expected behavior:

```
(defn factorial-2 [n]
  (reduce * 1N (range 1 (inc n))))
```

Comment: Thanks for additional insight!  I didn't realize the type of initial value to `reduce` changes the behavior .